# parsing a string by regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of

```
"name"=>"3B Ae", "note"=>"Test fddd \"33 Ae\" FIXME", "is_on"=>"keke, baba"
```

and i want to parse it by a java program into segments of

```
name
3B Ae
note
Test fddd \"33 Ae\" FIXME
is_on
keke, baba
```

It is noted that the contents of the string, i.e. `name`, `3B Ae`, are not fixed.
Any suggestion?

Comment: is your example one input string or multiple input strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you:

- replace => with :
- Wrap the full string with {}

The result will look like this, which is valid JSON. You can then use a JSON parser (GSON or Jackson, for example) to parse those values into a java object.

```
{
    "name": "3B Ae",
    "note": "Test fddd \"33 Ae\" FIXME",
    "is_on": "keke, baba"
}
```

If you have control over the process that produces this string, I highly recommend that you use a standard format like JSON or XML that can be parsed more easily on the other end.

Comment: This is really clever (good catch), but what if he doesn't control the input strings?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the quoting rules, I'm not certain that a regular expression (even a PCRE with negative lookbehinds) can parse this consistently. What you probably want is to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), or some other parser capable of handling a context-free language.

Answer (score -1):

If you can make sure your data (key or value) does not have a `=>` or a `,` (or find some other delimiters that will not occur), the solution is pretty simple:

- Split the string by `,` you get the `key => value` pairs
- Split the key `value => pairs` by `=>` you get what you want

if `inputString` holds
`"name"=>"3B Ae", "note"=>"Test fddd \"33 Ae\" FIXME", "is_on"=>"keke baba"`
(from a file for instance)
(I have changed the `,` to `;` from between `keke` and  `baba`)

```
    String[] keyValuePairs = inputString.split(",");
    for(String oneKeyValue : keyValuePairs)
    {
       String[] keyAndValue = oneKeyValue.split("=>");
    }
```

Comment: Splitting by , will not give name=>value pairs as a comma may appear inside of a value (e.g. "keke, baba")

Comment: @Moe, yes. That's how my answer starts _If you can make sure your data (key or value) does not have a => or a_, and I explicitly mention _(I have changed the , to ; from between keke and baba)_. If OP has control on the data, this should be easy to do and I think this is more straightforward (the JSON idea was cool, though)